# What type of import is this?

Tags: java

```
 public class Demo {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
         int number = input.nextInt();
         System.out.print(number);
     }
}
```

I found this in a book. Aren't you supposed to specifically import of wildcard import Scanner? Can you use java.util.Scanner without importing?

Comment: The only reason you import is so that you don't have to write it like this (because it's easier). If you don't import, you'll have to write it like this.

Comment: Um, yes. The only point of an import is so that you *don't* need to use fully-qualified names. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: `import` allows you do to a short hand version of this code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fully qualified name of the Scanner class. You can either import the Scanner class like you know it (as a normal import), or do it the way that it's done here. However, if you don't do the "normal" import then you will need the fully-qualified name any time you refer to the Scanner class.

For ease of readability, always import the class so that you don't need the fully-qualified name every time. It is both easier to read and write.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, and it's perfectly legal, the mean reason of using `import` in java is to save some keystrokes.